# perl move throws error, but does move the file

Tags: perl, move

I'm pretty new to perl and just found some very unexpected behaviour.

I use move from [`File::Copy`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aCopy) to rename a folder. It works as expected, but when I look at the return value variable `$!` afterwards, it shows an error.

The relevant code I use:

```
$helpr =~ s/\./ /g;

move($file,$helpr);
print $!;
```

The output:

```
[j@box test]$ ls
my.test.dir
[j@box test]$ fileRenamer.pl
No such file or directory
[j@box test]$ ls
my test dir
```

Why do I get an error code, when the job is done anyhow? What am I missing?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: The error message in English would be useful.

Comment: "Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden" => "File or directory not found"

Comment: @psxls The English version of this error is `No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mpapec says, you should not use the error message unless `move` returns a false value, e.g. with `... or die $!`. However, as to why this occurs:

I've seen this before, and it seems like `File::Copy` is setting `$!` spuriously. I looked at the source and found this line:

```
($tosz1,$tomt1) = (stat($to))[7,9];
```

Where `$to` is the file name that the file is being moved to. This check is made to handle exceptions made for overwriting files, and naturally if the file does not exist, `$!` will be set. I would classify this as a bug of sorts.

Comment: That's no bug, nor would a -e check change the situation, as -e is implemented in terms of stat().

Comment: @pilcrow As for -e, yes, I found that out when testing now, writing a bug report. Why would you say its not a bug?

Answer (score 3):

Checking on `$!` makes sense only when `move()` fails (returns false),

```
move($file,$helpr) or print $!;
```

Comment: But why is it even filled? When I print it before the move command, it does not contain an error.

Comment: @user2968944 it might be bug inside module, but `$!` is also set in simple script, ie. `perl -e 'print $!'` gives `No such file or directory`

Comment: @mpapec I tried that too, but for me it just prints an empty string.

Comment: @TLP it is on Centos, perl 5.10.1. On more recent strawberry there is empty string as you noticed. http://snag.gy/tqiG0.jpg

Comment: Indeed it seems to be OS/version dependent.

Comment: On Unix, perl's `$!` is `errno`, and there's no `errno` value, which says "no error". `errno` is only valid if a previous system call failed. The FreeBSD manpage says: "Successful calls never set errno; once set, it remains until another error occurs."